# how to handle on touch event of web-view on plain text and links.

Tags: android, android-webview, ontouchlistener

I want to show and hide another view on the click event of web view.
so i use **onTouchListener** for this purpose, Then hyper links in web view  doesn't work.
and i have also set **webviewclient** with my Web View.But it only follow onTouch event.
So please suggest me some idea to handle this situation.
Thanks.